# Container height issue HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, layout, height

Im wanting the container (purple border) to grow in size alongside the main content so i can place a border around it so it looks like the sidebar (blue border) is full height.

```
    <div id="container">
    <section id="mainContent">
        <h1>title here</h1>
            <img src="images/jayzmchg.jpg"></img>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
            Donec eget sapien ut eros auctor consectetur. Praesent pretium ante et orci pharetra venenatis.
            Proin fringilla fermentum sollicitudin. In ornare lectus ipsum, et egestas arcu consectetur 
            a. Nulla facilisi. Praesent id convallis arcu. Vestibulum leo tellus, hendrerit eu metus et, 
            cursus ultricies sapien. Aenean eu rutrum sem. Curabitur at quam nec augue viverra tempor ac 
            ut lorem. Sed vel accumsan sapien. Phasellus luctus diam ac luctus tincidunt. Integer quis 
            venenatis mauris. Nam malesuada augue id nibh porta commodo. Nam ullamcorper dui sit amet 
            ligula scelerisque hendrerit.</p>
    </section>

    <div id="sidebar">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<footer id="footer">
        <p></p>
</footer>
```

Above is the html, the following is the css

```
#container { /* purple border */
height: 250px;
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 1000px;
border: 1px solid #FF00FF;
    }

#mainContent { /*red border */
float: left;
width: 700px;
border: 1px solid #FF0000
    }

#sidebar {/*blue border */
width: 294px;
float: right;
border: 1px solid #0000FF;
    }
```

ive set the height at 250px for the container so you can see it, ive tried setting it as 100% but just doesnt show anything im guessing this is cause theres no content in it but how could i make it so it acts like if what is inside the mainContent is its height.

[image]

adding overflow:hidden to container causes this
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put a `float:left;` on #container.

OR

Put `overflow:hidden;` on #container to clear the internal floats.

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3jNTv/

Chris Coyier has written a great post about it here:
http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: overflow: hidden caused the following to occur (check edit to main post) as you can see it cut off the text on the bottom of mainContainer

Comment: my bad i had left the height: 250px for the example earlier, sorry! thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try set the height to `heigh: 100%;`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, see live example:

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/makypl/CHdsA/embedded/result/)

```
height: auto !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added a class floClear and add a div. it will work fine.

```
CSS

#container { /* purple border */

   margin: 0 auto;
   max-width: 1000px;
   border: 1px solid #FF00FF;
}

#mainContent { /*red border */ 
   float: left;
   width: 700px;
   border: 1px solid #FF0000
}

#sidebar {/*blue border */
   width: 294px;
   float: right;
   border: 1px solid #0000FF;
}

.floClear
{
   clear:both;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <section id="mainContent">
        <h1>title here</h1>
            <img src="images/jayzmchg.jpg"></img>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
            Donec eget sapien ut eros auctor consectetur. Praesent pretium ante et orci pharetra venenatis.
            Proin fringilla fermentum sollicitudin. In ornare lectus ipsum, et egestas arcu consectetur 
            a. Nulla facilisi. Praesent id convallis arcu. Vestibulum leo tellus, hendrerit eu metus et, 
            cursus ultricies sapien. Aenean eu rutrum sem. Curabitur at quam nec augue viverra tempor ac 
            ut lorem. Sed vel accumsan sapien. Phasellus luctus diam ac luctus tincidunt. Integer quis 
            venenatis mauris. Nam malesuada augue id nibh porta commodo. Nam ullamcorper dui sit amet 
            ligula scelerisque hendrerit.</p>
    </section>

    <div id="sidebar">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="floClear"></div>
</div>

<footer id="footer">
        <p>Test</p>
</footer>
```